# Chrome issue SVG transform

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, svg, transform

I'm trying to position a svg rectangle with transfrom=translate(). 
When I tested it, I saw that it doesn't work in Chrome but works nice in Firefox.

I also tried in Chrome with -webkit- but doesn't work either.

In the code snippet you can see whats the problem when its open with Chrome.

Does anyone now a workaround for this or am I doing something wrong?

```html
<svg transform="translate(100,0)">
  <rect width="200" height="200" style="fill:blue;;stroke:black" />
</svg>
<br><br>
<svg style="transform:translate(100px,0)">
  <rect width="200" height="200" style="fill:blue;;stroke:black" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suf2reee/

Comment: I think this may be related to the MathML support. In fact, if you check the transform attribute MDN documentation page, it warns you when you that CSS fallbacks are being used instead, as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/be7w0z (left firefox, right chrome). HOWEVER, if you apply the transform to the rectangle instead of the svg object, it will work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/suf2reee/1/

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a SVG 1.1 vs SVG 2 issue.  In SVG 1.1, which is the version that browsers generally support, the `transform` attribute was not valid for the `<svg>` element.  It *is* allowed in SVG 2.

Firefox have started implementing some SVG 2 features, whereas Chrome is not so far along.

The simplest solution is just to put your transform on the `<rect>`.

Comment: Yes @Paul LeBeau, I've had the similar issue and this works very nicely.