# Is it possible to apply transform to svg element?

Tags: svg.js

I'm learning how to use SVG.js and I'm having troubles applying transform (like skew, rotate, etc...) to svg (or g for that matter) tags.

The w3 says svg should support animateTransform : https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#SVGElement

A simplified example can be found here
https://jsfiddle.net/kuh2agfy/3/

```
svg.animate(1000,'', 0).skew(10,10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example seems to work just fine.

Beside that, it is *NOT* possible to transform the root-svg with the transform attribute.

It *IS* possible to use css transform for that matter.

Comment: My exemple does not work in my sense, since the svg containing the letter does not skew as I expect. And it's not the root-svg or is any nested svg considered a root-svg ?

Comment: but... it does? Well - at least in Firefox it does. Chrome seems to not doing anything. Nested svgs SHOULD work. I thought, when it works, then in chrome. But it looks like Chrome cant do it. you might be better off just using groups

Comment: @Coolseb I think the answer is in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726073/2129897

Comment: Ok, thanks Fuzzyma for the help. I'm using either safari or chrome, since I saw here many alerts that stuff were not supported in FF

Comment: Actually that's why I use Firefox. So I can see my code break :D

Comment: But as the other post says, even CSS transform does not work in all browsers yet :(

Comment: Yes I didn't know that too.